# boto3 giving Access Denied error while uploading file through python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, upload, boto3, access-denied

When I tried uploading an image to s3 using boto3 in python I am constantly getting errors.
The error says:

```py
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

My code for uploading the image is

```py
def upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name=None):
    """Upload a file to an S3 bucket

    :param file_name: File to upload
    :param bucket: Bucket to upload to
    :param object_name: S3 object name. If not specified then file_name is used
    :return: True if file was uploaded, else False
    """

    # If S3 object_name was not specified, use file_name
    if object_name is None:
        object_name = file_name

    # Upload the file
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        response = s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name, ExtraArgs={'ACL':'public-read'})
        print(response)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was very simple and easy, since I was not providing the ACCESS_KEY & SECRET_KEY, so AWS was not letting me upload image to s3.

I added both the access key and secret key to it while getting the client of s3 from boto3

```py
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
```

A good documentation of this is present [at boto documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html)